# ssh Mysql dump table parts (11GB DB to smaller pieces)

Tags: mysql, ssh

I'm facing the following:

We have a DB table of 11GB with over 257 million records and need a backup. Exporting via PHPmyAdmin isn't possible (chrome keeps crashing) and backing up with SSH mysqldump tablename will give a insufficient space disk error (error 28).

Now I'd like to know if there is a way to export a mysqldump with a row 0 till ~100.000.000 command so we can make 3 parts (or smaller parts if required).

What I'm using:

> mysqldump -p -u username database_name database_table > dbname.sql

[EDIT]

Found out how to get a row of <50.0000.0000 to SQL with the following:

> mysqldump -p -u db_name db_table --where='id<50000000'

But the big question remains now, how to go further? Now I want to get all records between 50.000.000 and 100.000.000 ..

Anybody knows the answer if it's possible and what command I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

Part 1 (<50.000.000):

> mysqldump -p -u db_name db_table --where='id<50000000' >part_1.sql

Part 2 (>50.000.000 till <100.0000.000):

> mysqldump -p -u db_name db_table --where='id>=50000000 &&
>   id<100000000' >part_2.sql

Part last (>250.000.000)

> mysqldump -p -u db_name db_table --where='id>250000000' >part_final.sql

And so on..

Comment: You're missing all between 100.000.000 to 250.000.000 - or were you just lazy typing this down too :P

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` creates a text file that contains sql statements, if want to take mysql backup in parts then you will have to run `mysqldump` like this

```
mysqldump --where "id%2=0" database_name table > table_even.sql
mysqldump --where "id%2=1" database_name table > table_odd.sql
```

OR

you need to write some program, script to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice solution for heavy transfers! This might also help you to avoid to transfer your database in parts (as in this example) - since it does this super fast:

1. Exporting a full database or in parts as mentioned using mysqldump:

   `mysqldump -p -u db_name db_table --where='id<50000000' >part_1.sql`
2. To import to the new database - login via terminal to the new database:

   `mysql -h localhost -upotato -p123456`
3. Enter the database:

   `USE databasename;`
4. Use the source command:

   `source /path/to/file.sql;`

This works X1000 faster than the standard:

```
mysql -h localhost_new -upotato -p1234567 table_name < /path/to/file.sql
```

Since you enter the database.